# How to aggregate data (or use a GROUP BY clause) without collapsing other columns?

Tags: sql

One example is I want to know which items cost more than the average price. So for the original table below:

| Item | Prices |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 2 |

The average price is 2.5, so my query would ideally select a third column `AVG(Prices) as avg` then I'd add a `HAVING Prices > avg` clause at the end. So the selected columns would look more like

| Item | Prices | avg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 2.5 |
| B | 2 | 2.5 |

The problem is, when I use an aggregate like `AVG()` it collapses the database into one row. Is there a way to only aggregate or `GROUP BY` one column then broadcasting to the number of rows?

Comment: Sorry for the tables not rendering, they render in preview but I added the code blocks in case they don't.

Comment: Like Error2646 suggests, it doesn't sound like you need to do a GROUP BY. `Item` is a unique identifier.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `GROUP_BY` in this example. Simply select the average as the third value of your `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT 
    item, 
    price, 
    (SELECT AVG(price) FROM products) as avg_price
FROM 
    products;
```

If you don't know, this is called subquery (as you see it is a `SELECT` inside a `SELECT`).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your dbms it probably supports window functions like this

```
select *,
       avg(price) over 
         ( partition by 1 ) as average_price
  from your_table
```

Or

```
select *,
       (select avg(price) 
          from your_table
       ) as average_price
  from your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a procedure to calculate the mean first and then to show only the records with higher prices, together with the mean value as a column.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE More_Expensive_than_Average()
BEGIN
    DECLARE @meanpr DECIMAL;
    SELECT AVG(Prices) INTO @meanpr FROM TABLE_NAME;
    SELECT Item, Prices, @meanpr AS average
    WHERE Prices > @meanpr;
END;
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 1):

Window functions could indeed be used to some extent, but (probably) not in a WHERE or HAVING clause that would directly enable some filter.

The usual way to obtain the required result would be to calculate the average price in a subquery, join that subquery, and use a WHERE-clause on the joined set.

Something like this:

```
select item, prices, avg
from mytable
cross join (
    select avg(prices) as avg
    from mytable
) as avgprice 
where prices > avg;
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned Window/Olap functions is your friend:

```
select item, price, avg(price) over () as avg_price
from item_prices
```

If you want to filter your result set, you typically add an outer select to that:

```
select * from (
    select item, price, avg(price) over () as avg_price
    from item_prices
) t
where price > avg_price;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yYRUkNnm)